# Paginate when order by sum relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

What's wrong in this request ?

```
$users = User::where('about', '!=', null)->with('tips')->paginate(12)->sortBy(function($user){
    return $user->tips->sum('amount');
})->reverse();
```

In the view there is the pagination code

```
{{$users->links()}}
```

And I have an error

```
Method links does not exist. (View: /Users/fab/Sites/tipme/resources/views/users.blade.php)
```

Comment: dd($users); see what you get

Comment: Collection {#313 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    1 => User {#304 ▶}
    0 => User {#303 ▶}
  ]
}

Comment: put your `sortBy()` before paginate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

```
$paginated_users = User::where('about', '!=', null)->withSum('tips', 'amount')->orderByDesc('tips_sum_amount')->paginate(12);
```